Update Perl on Ubuntu server
My customer has an Ubuntu server "22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1022-azure x86_64)" running Apache with mod-perl. Installed Perl version is 5.34. Recently I was asked by business owner to update the Perl to 5.40 due to some vulnerabilities found in 5.34. Unfortunately I'm rather a developer and can only do simplest administrative operations on Ubuntu so this is something completely new for me.
I started from "sudo apt update" and then "apt-list--upgradable". There are some packages but only "libdpkg-perl" seems having some relation to Perl. According to its description that is not what I'm looking for. I found a list of modules which were installed on that machine. Some from them look like related to web site:

apache2
perl
libapache2-mod-perl2
libapache2-mod-perl2-dev
libgd-dev
libgd-graph-perl
libapr1-dev
libssl-dev
libxml2-dev
libxml-libxml-perl
libxml-libxslt-perl
libapache2-request-perl
cpanminus

All these modules are not listed as having upgrades. So, how to upgrade Perl? Is it possible at all without updating the whole system? Thank you in advance!

"Recently I was asked by business owner to update the Perl to 5.40 due to some vulnerabilities found in 5.34. Unfortunately I'm rather a developer"  I would refuse this on a productionserver. Let an admin do that.. Mind that Ubuntu backports vulnerabilities so updating Ubuntu might be enough but even that comes with risks. Any risk on a production server should be avoided.

You are essentially asking for a primer on how Ubuntu security and package management work. Do a bit more searching: It has been explained many times in many places why your customer is asking for the wrong action. Example Another example Yet another example

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS is still supported, which means the vulnerabilities have been most probably patched (you can update the question with CVE numbers so we can verify it).
It seems you're using the system Perl, so to update it, you need to update the whole system. The current version is 24.10 which features perl 5.38.2 according to ubuntu packages.
